# Delete first n rows in column vector in Matlab & call array rows by an array of indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indices

I have 2 questions.

*Question 1:*

I have a column vector, `v`, with (say) 1000 rows. I want to delete first (say) `n` rows (for example `n=300` to remove the first 300 rows of `v`).

*Question 2:*

I have an array of indices. How can it be used to get rows of another array whose index values are in first array?

```
I = [ 1 2 4 5] %// array of indices

Q = [ 45 22 66 87 99 10 ] %// input array
```

Desired Output:

```
O = [45 22 87 99] %// output array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you first question:

```
N=300;
v=rand(1000,1); %// sample data
v(1:N)=[];
```

And the second:

```
O=Q(I)
```

Comment: Alternatively, v = v(n+1:length(v)).